# r stat_regline_equation() intercept and slope issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, lme4

My issue is the `intercept` and `slope` from `stat_regline_equation()` shown on plot does not match the `intercept` and `slope` from model fit `ldply(modelfit, coef)`, the later was what I was expecting on the plot.

Here's how we reproduce this issue.

**First**, I start with a toy dataset.

```
   library(lme4)
   data(Soybean)
   library(plyr)
   library(nlme)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(ggpubr)
   library(lemon)

head(Soybean)

       Plot   Variety Year Time weight  
1988.1 1988F1       F 1988   14  0.106 
1988.2 1988F1       F 1988   21  0.261 
1988.3 1988F1       F 1988   28  0.666  
1988.4 1988F1       F 1988   35  2.110  
1988.5 1988F1       F 1988   42  3.560  
1988.6 1988F1       F 1988   49  6.230
```

**Second**, I fit model with Variety as random intercept on each subset of dataset by Year.

```
table(Soybean$Year)

1988 1989 1990 
 156  128  128 
 
table(Soybean$Variety)

  F   P 
204 208 

# Fit LME model for each subset(Soybean)
MxM1 <- dlply(Soybean,
                    "Year",
                    function(x)
                      lme(fixed = weight ~ Time,
                          random = ~ 1 |Variety ,
                           data=x, na.action=na.exclude))
```

These are the coefficients of Random intercept (Variety) from the model. 2 varieties, 3 years , 6 different intercepts, this makes sense.

```
  ldply(MxM1, coef)
  Year (Intercept)  Time
1 1988       -8.65 0.349
2 1988       -7.73 0.349
3 1989       -6.71 0.242
4 1989       -4.04 0.242
5 1990       -7.28 0.309
6 1990       -6.63 0.309
```

**Third**, I estimate yhat (weight)

```
Soybean <- by(Soybean, Soybean$Year, \(x) {
  fit <- lme(fixed = weight ~ Time,
             random = ~ 1 |Variety ,
             data=x, na.action=na.exclude)
  cbind(x, yhat=predict(fit, na.action=na.exclude))
}) |> do.call(what=rbind)

         Plot Variety Year Time weight  yhat
1988.1 1988F1       F 1988   14  0.106 -3.76
1988.2 1988F1       F 1988   21  0.261 -1.32
1988.3 1988F1       F 1988   28  0.666  1.12
1988.4 1988F1       F 1988   35  2.110  3.57
1988.5 1988F1       F 1988   42  3.560  6.01
1988.6 1988F1       F 1988   49  6.230  8.45
```

**Fourth**: I am plotting a scatter plot, x axis : Time, y axis: weight, a regression line through the scatter plot based on yhat values. I see

```
ggplot(data = Soybean, 
       aes (x=Time, y = weight))+
  geom_point(size =3)+
  geom_line(aes(y=yhat))+
  stat_regline_equation()+
  theme_classic()+
  facet_rep_grid(Variety~Year)
```

[image]

I was **expecting** a regression line with slope and intercept

```
  ldply(MxM1, coef)
  Year (Intercept)  Time
1 1988       -8.65 0.349
2 1988       -7.73 0.349

3 1989       -6.71 0.242
4 1989       -4.04 0.242

5 1990       -7.28 0.309
6 1990       -6.63 0.309
```

[image]

because the `yhat` predicted values are based on estimates from `ldply(MxM1, coef)`, so when I use the `stat_regline_equation()` function I was expecting a line estimates from `ldply(MxM1, coef)` , however this is not what I see. and I am not sure why `stat_regline_equation()` is ignoring the values from `yhat` and plotting a regression line using `lm` function ?

Any suggestion on how to plot regression line with yhat and estimates(slope and intercept) from `ldply(MxM1, coef)` is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make sense that these two things are not giving you the same information. From the documentation of `stat_regline_equation()` each line is estimated using `lm()`:

```
Add regression line equation and R^2 to a ggplot. Regression model is fitted using the function lm.
```

As you have faceted by both `Variety` and `Year`, it is fitting a separate line for each of the six facets. To illustrate this, we can subset the data for just 1988 and fit a model with the interaction of `Time` and `Variety`:

```
Soybean1988 <- Soybean[Soybean$Year == "1988",]

model_1988 <- lm(weight ~ Time * Variety, data = Soybean1988)

summary(model_1988)
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ Time * Variety, data = Soybean1988)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.5718 -2.1753 -0.6001  1.2478 10.3532 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -7.68423    0.71742 -10.711   <2e-16 ***
Time           0.32545    0.01474  22.085   <2e-16 ***
VarietyP      -0.96067    1.00934  -0.952   0.3427    
Time:VarietyP  0.04550    0.02052   2.218   0.0281 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.567 on 152 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8855,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8833 
F-statistic:   392 on 3 and 152 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If we look at your plot, for Variety F the Intercept is -7.7 and the slope is 3.3. This matches the information reported in `(Intercept)` and `Time`. `VarietyP` is the change between the average of the two varieties, which is equal to the difference between -7.7 is the top left of the plot and -8.6 in the bottom left. Likewise `Time:VarietyP` is the difference in the slopes.

I hope this helps clear up the differences you found here.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. So it looks like `stat_regline_equation()` is not going to give me what I am expecting.  The question is how to plot regression line with estimates(slope and intercept) from the random effects estimates, ?